# How to do notifications

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on building a "social networking" site, basically theres a login and a forum where users can post, a gallery where you can upload pictures, send friend requests.

What I wanna do next is creating some kind of way a user can now someone has replied to a post they've made, if someone has sent them a friend request, tagged in a pic etc. Notifications.

This is kind of advanced to me so I felt I had to ask what would be the best way to do this, how do big sites do it?

Right now I'm thinking making a table "notifications"

```
id, user1, user2, type, link, have_read
```

And when for example I reply to a post by user Tom, I insert to that table

```
insert (Tom, Bob, 'post-reply', 'link to the post'
```

and if Tom sends Bob a friend request

```
insert (Tom, Bob, 'friend-request', 'link to where you can accept request'
```

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: A simple but probably unefficient way to do it could be adding more columns to your table (for example, booleans: `user1_read` and `user2_read`). Check the table when loading the page and if the user is either `user1` or `user2` and the read attribute is `false` for that user, add a notification "alert" (a badge?) that alerts the user. When opening the link, update the table for setting `true` to the read column. Do this update before reading on every page load.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Boolean "Notify" set to true once a request has been made.

If the Boolean is true you can add a notification bar which shows a message if the notify boolean is so to true